# Gifted Android Huawei Media Pad hard reset not working, what to do?

Tags: huawei

I was gifted a Huawei Media Pad, Model BG2-W09, from an elderly woman who no longer used it, and have factory reset, and tried to hard reset it to no avail. I would like to use it, but the how-to guides have all failed me. Please advice, ladies and gentlemen. it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

HardReset.info:
Afterwards press and hold the Volume Up + Power button at the same time for a few seconds.Wipe data on HUAWEI MediaPad T3 7

Relase held keys as soon as the Huawei logo appears on the screen.
Use the Volume buttons to scroll to "wipe data/factory reset" and confirm that option with the Power button.Format HUAWEI MediaPad T3 7
Once more choose "wipe data/factory reset"  from the menu and accept it with Power key.Restore HUAWEI MediaPad T3 7

Now accept option "reboot system now" by using Power button.Master Reset HUAWEI MediaPad T3 7
The factory reset will be completed as soon as the HUAWEI Welcome Panel shows up.
Congratulations! You have just performed the hard reset operation

Comment: Will this disable the last user's google account as well? Because that's the point that i get to with factory resets and such and cant get around in order to put my account on the device. i'm unable to set up my account to access the device. so if this will do that, i will give it a try. i'll post again whether it works or not. Thank you.

Comment: I still can't get past the verify google account, due to an "unknown error.", and don't have the previous users information. Is there a way to get around that as well?